# Unable to run Django with PostgreSQL in Docker

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I wanted to set up a Django app with PostgresDb inside docker containers so that's why I wanted to setup docker-compose but when I execute my code docker, django and db all are working fine and I also developed some API's and they were also working fine as expected but unfortunately, suddenly I'm blocked with these errors:

[image]

```js
pgdb_1    | 
pgdb_1    | 2021-12-11 15:05:38.674 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
pgdb_1    | 2021-12-11 15:05:38.674 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
pgdb_1    | 2021-12-11 15:05:38.674 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
pgdb_1    | 2021-12-11 15:05:38.697 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
pgdb_1    | 2021-12-11 15:05:38.729 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-12-11 15:03:09 UTC
pgdb_1    | 2021-12-11 15:05:38.761 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
django_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
django_1  | Performing system checks...
django_1  | 
django_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
pgdb_1    | 2021-12-11 15:05:41.390 UTC [34] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
pgdb_1    | 2021-12-11 15:05:41.390 UTC [34] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
pgdb_1    |     Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
django_1  | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
django_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
django_1  |     self.connect()
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
django_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
django_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
django_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
django_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
django_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django_1  | psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
django_1  | 
django_1  | 
django_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
django_1  | 
django_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
django_1  |     self.run()
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
django_1  |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
django_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
django_1  |     self.check_migrations()
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check_migrations
django_1  |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
django_1  |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
django_1  |     self.build_graph()
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 220, in build_graph
django_1  |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
django_1  |     if self.has_table():
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
django_1  |     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
django_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
django_1  |     return self._cursor()
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
django_1  |     self.ensure_connection()
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
django_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 218, in ensure_connection
django_1  |     with self.wrap_database_errors:
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
django_1  |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
django_1  |     self.connect()
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
django_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
django_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
django_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
django_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
django_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

My Dockerfile

```js
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml

```js
version: "3.8"
   
services:
  pgdb:
    image: "postgres"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=digipm
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  django:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - pgdb
```

Database config settings.py

```js
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'digipm',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'pgdb',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `DATABASES` definition in django settings file?

Comment: @jorf.brunning I have attached the DB config pls have a look. thanks

Comment: Settings vis-a-vis docker-compose look good. Your dockerfile is completely reasonable. What are the contents of `./data/db` that you are adding as a volume to the postgres container? When I run postgresql inside a container, I add no volumes from outside the container.

Comment: inside .`/data/db` I have all the file related to postgres eg: pg_hba.conf

Comment: It's possible you are injecting postgres config via that volume that the postgres installation inside your container does not expect. Have you edited anything inside pg_hba that might affect your default postgres user? You might try running the postgres container via docker compose without the volume.

Comment: then what should be the volume for postgress ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240045/discussion-between-jorf-brunning-and-zain-khan).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem where django isn't connecting to the database as I was trying to create a new django developement environment using docker. I created a new project `docker-compose run web django-admin startproject django_src .` then `docker-compose up` and behold it ain't connecting to the database.

I solved the problem after adding environment configuration in `docker-compose` on both the database and Django itself (See code snippets below). Then I made use of os.environ.get('') for host, name, user & password to give definite references to and fro docker-compose environment configuration.

Then I ran the following:

docker-compose run --rm app python manage.py migrate

docker-compose run --rm app python manage.py createsuperuser

Creating docker-django-postgres_app_run ... done
Username (leave blank to use 'user'):
Email address:
Password:
Password (again):
This password is too common.
Bypass password validation and create user anyway? [y/N]: y
Superuser created successfully.

**Dockerfile**

```html
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

**docker-composefile**

```html
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**settings.py**

```html
import os

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

requirements.txt

```html
asgiref==3.4.1
Django==4.0.1
psycopg2==2.9.3
sqlparse==0.4.2
```